# How to get path to the current SCons executable in a SCons script?

Tags: scons

I'm trying to build an executable from another external SCons project to use it in my SCons build.

At first I tried to run:

```py
Command('other_project_dir/executable', None, 'scons -C other_project_dir')
```

This doesn't work because SCons by default doesn't use the system `PATH` variable.

Even if it would work, another issue would be that is someone called my script with a custom path to SCons. The other script would still be built with the default SCons.

In conclusion, I need find out what is the path of the SCons that is currently running.
Is there any method to get it, or an environment variable that stores it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (in version `4.3.0`) SCons doesn't have a built in way to obtain its path.

However, you don't really need any special functions. You can just use plain Python:

```py
import sys
scons_path = sys.argv[0]

Command('other_project_dir/executable', scons_path, '$SOURCE -C other_project_dir')
```

Don't try to use the variable `__file__`.
It is purposely removed by SCons.

---

BTW, you should run `AlwaysRun('other_project_dir/executable')`.
Otherwise, SCons may not rebuild the other project when it's necessary since it isn't aware of the dependencies in the other project.